# Java - Get 3D point from 2D point and OpenCV camera calibration

Tags: python, java, opencv, camera-calibration, 2d-3d-conversion

Good morning,
I'm new to the subject and I need some information on this question:
I have received a file which provides the following calibration data for a camera:

Extrinsic calibration:
`< opencv_storage >`
`< rvec >`
`1.759099006652832 0.46710100769996643 -0.331699013710022`
`< /rvec >`
`< tvec >`
`-525.8941650390625 45.40763473510742 986.7235107421875`
`< /tvec >`
`< /opencv_storage >`

Intrisic calibration value:
`< opencv_storage >`
`< camera_matrix type_id="opencv-matrix" >`
`< rows >3< /rows >`
`< cols >3< /cols >`
`< dt >d< /dt >`
`1743.4478759765625 0.0 934.5202026367188 0.0 1735.1566162109375 444.3987731933594 0.0 0.0 1.0`
`< /data >`
`< /camera_matrix >`
`< distortion_coefficients type_id="opencv-matrix" >`
`< rows >5< /rows >`
`< cols >1< /cols >`
`< dt >d< /dt >`
`< data >`
`-0.43248599767684937 0.6106230020523071 0.008233999833464622 0.0018599999602884054 -0.6923710107803345`
`< /data >`
`< /distortion_coefficients >`
`< /opencv_storage >`

given a 2d point of the camera image how can i calculate the respective 3d point?

is this data enough to calculate the respective 3d point?

Comment: with just image points and calibration you cant compute a 3D information, because it can be on any depth along a ray. To define the ray you need the calibration, but it can't tell you magically, where on the ray the point is. If you have second ray (like a second camera with that point) you can intersect both rays (or find their closest distance point) and that's your point in 3D. Or, if you have 2 points with 1 ray each and you know the real world distance between those points, you can determine the points on both rays which have that known distance to each other.

Comment: Hi Micka,
I have two cameras available with their respective calibrations: intrinsic values ​​and extrinsic velocities for each camera.
The intrinsic and extrinsic values ​​are different for each camera and are described as mentioned in the post above

obviously the 2d points for an object seen from the two cameras are different as they refer to the respective position in the image.

Do you know if there is a java or python procedure that allows me to calculate the intersection of the rays of the two cameras?